# JS redirect page up one level

Tags: javascript

I have a simple question, below My JS function is to redirect the page if open using iPad.

I have a page mobile.abc.com, now what I want to do is redirect it if open using ipad to mobile.abc.com

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
       location.replace("../mobile.abc.com");
    }
```

I tried the that JS, but it's show wrong url to be : abc.com/mobile.abc.com

Any idea ?

Comment: Why the `../` path selector? Why not just `http://mobile.abc.com/`? Why beat around the bush?

Comment: I tried now ok. Thanks. Like the title, that's a simple question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
location.replace("//mobile.abc.com");
```

This will work for both `http` or `https`.

Comment: Do you think the `.replace()` is a mistake?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think `.replace()` is better here.

Comment: What is it going to do written like that? I would think it needs to have both the subject and the replacement, `location.replace("//abc.com", "//mobile.abc.com");`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Using replace() the current page will not be saved in session history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to it.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it in the console and see what it does. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish This is the `window.location`'s replace method, not string's.